# Set recyclerview children equal width depending on the parent width

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to create a list of views that align horizontally using recyclerview. I want to be split the width of the recyclerview equally so that all those views can fit inside a single line. view count is dynamic

Here is a simple final result, I created this using HTML and CSS.

[image: demo image]

Can I achieve the same in android using recyclerview?

Following is my recyclerview adapter, `holder.root` is the container for every view. I was thinking about getting the recyclerview width and divide that by number of views and setting that value as width for every view.

```
class ThreadsAdapter(
    private val threads: ArrayList<ThreadInfo>
): RecyclerView.Adapter<ThreadsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.layout_progress_thread, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return threads.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.root.layoutParams.width = 40 // just testing
    }


    class ViewHolder(v: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {
        val progressBar: ProgressBar = v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar)
        var root: ConstraintLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.root)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think, GridLayoutManager is specifically for this. (if i am understanding your question properly)

Comment: I tried with GridLayoutManager but every view take 100% width and making a vertical scroll to see the next view

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I found this library on Github, allow me to use Flexbox layout in android

https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout